# How to add offline event handling in Openfire plugin?

Tags: java, event-handling, openfire

I am java newbie . I need to handle offline sessions in Openfire plugin. From plugin development doc I am able to understand the basics , but I am not getting how can I handle offline event of openfire.
There is a class "SessionEventDispatcher" in package org.jivesoftware.openfire.event

There we have following predefined events:

```
session_created
session_destroyed
anonymous_session_created
anonymous_session_destroyed
resource_bound
```

These events then have listener , which is implemented in the Presence plugin.
Please help me understand how to proceed if I need to add offline event as well.

I am saving online users in redis but some how user sessions in openfire is less than users in redis, which means I am not handling some offline event in my plugin due to which user session is created and get added in redis , but user session is not closed explicitly which is handled to get remove from redis, and I face this discrepancy.

Comment: Can you explain your scenario for better understanding? like if you want to handle offline messages for any user?

Answer (score 0):

please correct me if I don`t understand your question clearly.
Do you examine interface org.jivesoftware.openfire.user.PresenceEventListener?
For example I implement that interface :

```
public class CustomPresenceEventListener implements PresenceEventListener {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomPresenceEventListener.class);

@Override
public void availableSession(ClientSession session, Presence presence) {
    LOG.info("\n\n=======SESSION AVAILABLE=========\n");
    try {
        LOG.info("USER : {}", session.getUsername());
    } catch (UserNotFoundException e) {
        LOG.info(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    LOG.info("\n================\n\n");
}

@Override
public void unavailableSession(ClientSession session, Presence presence) {
    LOG.info("\n\n=======SESSION UNAVAILABLE=========\n");
    try {
        LOG.info("USER : {}", session.getUsername());
    } catch (UserNotFoundException e) {
        LOG.info(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    LOG.info("\n================\n\n");
}

@Override
public void presenceChanged(ClientSession session, Presence presence) {
}

@Override
public void subscribedToPresence(JID subscriberJID, JID authorizerJID) {

}

@Override
public void unsubscribedToPresence(JID unsubscriberJID, JID recipientJID) {

}
```

And add/remove this listener with :

```
PresenceEventDispatcher.addListener(presenceEventListener);
PresenceEventDispatcher.removeListener(presenceEventListener);
```

And when I connect to Openfire I will see in the file info.log something like that :
=======SESSION AVAILABLE=========
2017.03.29 14:27:01 .CustomPresenceEventListener - USER : 25

## 2017.03.29 14:27:01 .CustomPresenceEventListener -

And when I leave Openfire logs will be :
=======SESSION UNAVAILABLE=========
2017.03.29 14:27:34  .CustomPresenceEventListener - USER : 25

## 2017.03.29 14:27:34  .CustomPresenceEventListener -

So you could add any action you want when user enter/leave Openfire.